# How to calculate the mean and variance of a uniformly distributed data set

Tags: standard-deviation

I generated a series of 20 numbers uniformly distributed in the interval [0,1].

i   Ui

1   0.179249377

2   0.55231524

3   0.845266587

4   0.335790807

5   0.755363948

6   0.136198531

7   0.641448669

8   0.479322568

9   0.779031078

10  0.610433663

11  0.989860381

12  0.765129741

13  0.840363047

14  0.255395385

15  0.002587429

16  0.311871613

17  0.081981029

18  0.791845714

19  0.896312967

20  0.858145209

**For Uniform distribution**

*mean = (a+b)/2*

*variance = (b-a)<sup>2</sup>/12*

Does this mean that for this data set:

*mean = (min+max)/2 = (0.002587+0.989860)/2 = 0.4962*

*variance = (max-min)<sup>2</sup>/12 =(0.989860-0.002587)<sup>2</sup>/12=0.0812*

Or would I calculate the mean and variance for this data set the regular way?

*mean = ∑Ui/20 = 0.5554*

*variance = ∑(Ui-μ)<sup>2</sup>/20-1 = 0.0954*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in the regular way.

The formulae
$$\text{mean}=\frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$\text{variance}=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$$

are theoretical value (population mean and variance) for uniform distribution in $[a,b]$, to which your estimators (sample mean and unbiased estimator of variance) should approach when the number of data tends to infinity.

Comment: (1) Because the question asks about "this data set," this answer doesn't seem appropriate.  (2) Please check the formula for the variance: its units of  measurement are incorrect and therefore it cannot possibly be right.  You likely meant to square the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the mean and variance of a sample, you needn't know the distribution.

$$\bar u=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n u_k,$$ and

$$\text{var}(u)=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n(u_k-\bar u)^2.$$

---

If you are after the mean and variance of the distribution itself, they are

$$\frac12$$ and $$\frac1{12}.$$